# How to disable a series of buttons using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do you disable the prev button when the previous month is less than the current month? For instance, if the current month is June, then I want to disable the prev month button so that they cant edit the month of May and the rest of it

```
 for(x=1;x<=12;x++){                         
    contents += '<td> <input type="button" name="x" id="'+x+'" class="reupload btn btn-primary '+ disabled_class + '" value="Add" ></td>';

     }
```

Comment: _"the previous months button"_ - What previous months button?

Comment: Please show us the relevant simplified code

Comment: We can only make assumptions of what you're referring too as we don't have a clue what your layout code looks like or what plugin you might be using for the calendar. Please update with more information.

Comment: Is that you datepicker or is it the jquery datepicker? If it's yours try to catch the click event and then do a check about the month. I its the jquery one then I'm sure they have done plenty of cunction to handle that.

Comment: How do you disable the prev button when the previous month is less than the current month?

For instance, if the current month is June, then I want to disable the prev month button so that they cant edit the month of May and the rest of it

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .attr() function to add the "disabled" attribute. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Without code to see, I can't be sure this will help.

But here's what would work:

`$(e).prev().attr("disabled", "disabled"); //get previous sibling and disable it`

To get the previous sibling so if you had like 4 adjacent buttons it would work.

Code would look something like this:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
    var id = e.id;
    $(e).prev().attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

However you'd need some logic for first and last..

Comment: for(x=1;x<=12;x++){                         
    contents += '<td> <input type="button" name="x" id="'+x+'" class="reupload btn btn-primary '+ disabled_class + '" value="Add" ></td>';

     }

Answer (score 0):

put a html attribute on your buttons, with the value of the month (ex : january = 1, etc etc)
Then, in your callback function, get the value of that attribute for the button clicked, and write a reverse-counting loop to disable all the previous ones with attributes selectors (or put that number somewhere in the id of the button so you can select by id instead).

Should work alright.